# Rebol simulating unlimited args any example from what is said here?

Tags: rebol

http://www.rebol.org/ml-display-thread.r?m=rmlJNWS

Graham wrote:

> Can a function have a variable number of arguments?
>   No. But you can simulate it, by using 'any-type! function specifiers and passing unset! as arguments. Better is to use refinements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rebol's default dialect (the `do` dialect) does not support the notion of a call to a function having a variable number of arguments.  If you want to break a rule as fundamental as this, then you need your own dialect.  Nothing stopping you from making:

```
tweet [Hello World How Are You Today?]
```

But the idea of using `word!` instead of `string!` in this case is a little dodgy, as many common tweets aren't valid for the Rebol parser:

```
tweet [LOL! :)]
```

Neglecting that issue, note that by default you won't get any expression evaluation.  So this `tweet` dialect would have to choose a way to show where you want an evaluation.  You might use get-word elements to do variable substitution, and parentheses for more general evaluations:

```
>> a: 10
>> b: 20
>> tweet [When you add :a and :b you get (a + b), LOL ":)"]
"When you add 10 and 20 you get 30, LOL :)"
```

BTW, `take-n` in Rowland's example isn't returning a block.  Not directly, I mean.  It's perhaps better understood with parentheses, and by addressing the implicit "do" that's there on every interpretation:

```
do [do (take-n 4) 1 2 3 4]
```

`take-n` works with only one parameter (the "n") and then returns a function which takes n parameters.  Let's call that function f, so step one of this evaluation turns into something equivalent to:

```
do [f 1 2 3 4]
```

When the second do kicks in, that function gets run...and it's returning a block.  In practice, I doubt you're going to want to be counting the parameters like this.

Comment: Thanks a lot hostilefork your answers are always thoughtfull, I will have a long week-end to read all of them thorougly :)

Answer (score 1):

The answer on that page is:

yes, a function can have a variable number of arguments. Do is such a function, as e.g. in:

```
take-n: func [n /local spec] [ 
     spec: copy [] 
     for i 1 n 1 [ 
         append spec to word! append copy "a" to string! i 
     ]
     func spec reduce [:reduce append reduce [to lit-word! append copy "take" to string! n] spec]
]
do take-n 4 1 2 3 4 
== [take4 1 2 3 4]
```

Comment: take-n returns a block so this is one argument. In fact I didn't ask the right question, I rather want to be able to write something like
tweet Hello World instead of tweet "Hello World".

Finally I found a way.